# Diffrent layout for posts

Tags: posts, loop

I have two rows to display posts
in first row i have two posts image + content , image + content
And in second row the post layout change means content + image , content + image
can you solve this my problem 
this is my code :

```
<div class="main_blog_content">                                         
    <?php $arr = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    );?>                                                
    <?php
        $arrg_query = new WP_Query($arr);

        if(have_posts() ) : while($arrg_query ->have_posts() ) : $arrg_query ->the_post();
        foreach ($arr as $i):
            $i++;
            // one layout type
            if($i%2 == 0):
        ?>                                                  
            <div class="col-sm-6">                                                  
                <div class="single_blog_area textwhite">                                
                    <div class="row">                                                                   
                        <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding">                                       
                            <div class="single_blog_img">                                           
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>                                          
                                <!--<img src="<?php //echo get_bloginfo('template_url');?>/assets/images/blog1.jpg" alt="" />-->                                        
                            </div>                                  
                        </div>                                  
                        <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding">                                                                           
                            <div class="single_blog_text s_b_left">                                         
                                <p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                        <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></a>
                                </p>                                            <h3>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>                                          
                                <div class="separator2">
                                </div>                                          
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>                                          
                                <p>
                                    <?php echo wp_trim_words($content, 43); ?>
                                </p>                                                
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read_more">Read More >></a>                                      
                            </div>                                  
                        </div>                                                                  
                    </div>                          
                </div>                      
            </div>                      
        <?php
            // another layout type
            else:?>                                                                              
                <div class="col-sm-6">                                        
                    <div class="single_blog_area textwhite">                                            
                        <div class="row">                                                     
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 no-padding">                                                    
                                <div class="single_blog_img">                                                   
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>                                                        
                                    <!--<img src="assets/images/blog3.jpg" alt="" />-->                                                    
                                </div>                                                
                            </div>                                                     
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 no-padding">                                                    
                                <div class="single_blog_text s_b_right">                                                        
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                            <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></a>
                                    </p>                                                        
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                    </h3>                                                        
                                    <div class="separator2">
                                    </div>                                                        
                                    <?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>                                                      
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo wp_trim_words($content, 43); ?>
                                    </p>                                                             
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="read_more">Read More >></a>                                                    
                                </div>                                                
                            </div>                                                 
                        </div>                                        
                    </div>                                    
                </div>                              
        <?php endif;?>                          
    <?php endforeach; ?>                    
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>                   
</div>
```

i send a image of posts that i want :  [image]

Comment: yes its same questions, but its not solved , so i add a image in second questions to show what i want

Comment: Layout problems should be solved with CSS. I suggest looking into `flex` and its property `order`. You can also select ranges of elements with `:nth-child(n+2)` for example. I would write an answer but this question will probably be marked as off-topic by the end of the day... so, good luck.